# jQuery working some pages, but not all

Tags: jquery

I've added a search function to each page of my website. It was working perfectly, but for reasons unknown it now only works on the homepage: http://www.championfreight.co.nz/

```
<select id="urlSelect" class="Regular" style="cursor: pointer; height: 28px; width: 200px" onchange="window.location = jQuery('#urlSelect option:selected').val();">  
<option value="http://www.championfreight.co.nz/index">&nbsp;I need...</option>  
<option value="http://www.championfreight.co.nz/quote">&nbsp;A freight quote</option>  
<option value="http://www.championfreight.co.nz/services">&nbsp;List of services</option>  
<option value="http://www.championfreight.co.nz/contact">&nbsp;Contact information</option>   
<option value="http://www.championfreight.co.nz/schedules">&nbsp;Shipping schedules</option>  
<option value="http://www.championfreight.co.nz/tracking">&nbsp;Freight tracking</option>  
</select>
```

I can't work out why this isn't working. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Checked the console for errors?

Answer (score 2):

You're only including jQuery on the home page. You need to include it on every page.

Answer (score 1):

include jquery on all pages

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Exists on home page but not on others